# Passing Int Array to ASP .NET Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass an array to a Controller for the purpose of updating those matched records
Here is how I'm passing the array:

```
[Route("api/updateFile/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public void updateFile(int[] ids, string FolderName, Int Key)
    {
        var FilesToUpdate = db.ActivityFiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == ids); //ids containing 124,52,22,262,32
        FilesToUpdate.id= FolderName;
        FilesToUpdate.Key = Key;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The Ajax is pretty simple

```
$.ajax({url: '/api/updateFile/' + imgList  + '?FolderName=' + 545454 + '&Key=' + 777,
type: "GET",success: function (data) {console.log("image set updated - success! ");},
error: function (data) {}});
```

**imgList**  contains: `124,52,22,262,32`
But this seems to never work, is there a better approach to archiving what I'm trying to archive?

Comment: i wouldn't do a url like that.

Comment: You need a custom model binder for that. Google for ArrayModelBinder, pretty sure there's blog posts for that

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, that was for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an array through api then you need to send it via request body, then you need to update your code like this

First create a ModelBind class that stores the array

Model.cs

```
namespace Api.Models
{
  public class Model
  {
    public int[] ids {get; set;}
  }
}
```

```
    [Route("api/updateFile")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void updateFile([FromBody] Model model, string FolderName, int Key)
    {
         // your code goes here in the ids parameter you have the array
    }
```

Then you need to change your petition to send a Post Request and in the request body you need to send an object like

```
 {
   "ids" : [124,52,22,262,32]
 }
```

Check the Ajax documentation to send a post request with a request body, remember that by default the C# controller get the Content-Type as application/json then take into account this in your Ajax request if you get problems.

Comment: I like this! giving it a shot!

Comment: @cinafoy881 Thanks, also you can try the second solution, you can pass the array directly as you can see, then both solutions are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this controller action header:

```
     [Route("api/updateFile/{folderName}/{key}")]
      public void updateFile([FromBody]int[] ids, string folderName, int key)
    {
   var filesToUpdate = db.ActivityFiles.FirstOrDefault(x => ids.Contains(x.id) ); 
        filesToUpdate.id= folderName;
        filesToUpdate.Key = key;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

and this Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/api/updateFile/545454/777',
data: [124,52,22,262,32],
success: function (result) {console.log("image set updated - success! ");},
error: function (err) {}
});
```